# How do I display several images inline and centered with html/css?

Tags: html, css, inline, center, footer

I'm trying to place the six icons on the footer in center and inline. I've tried everything I can think of and all the suggestions I've found on this forum, but nothing has worked. Any idea how I can achieve this simple task?

The url is http://www.spanish-bookworld.com/delete-footer.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your `.socialMedia` element these rules:

```
#footerWrapping .socialMedia {    
 padding: 40px 0px 20px 0px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It worked. I also removed "inline-block", which was stopping the other commands from working. Thanks.

Comment: @Maria exactly! glad it helps

Answer (score 0):

set the width of div #footerwrapping to 50%, then it centers the icons on the page